# Java Method Definition Compile Error Wilcard

Tags: java, generics, wildcard

I have a method which called getExcludeMethodList() I face compile error on eclipse.

my method signature

```
private List<String> getExcludeMethodList(List<T> data, List<String> filteredList) {

 List<String> excludeList= new ArrayList<>();

    //.........

     return excludeList;
}
```

but eclipse enforce me to do using

```
private static <T> List<String> getExcludeMethodList(List<T> data, List<String> filteredList) {
List<String> excludeList= new ArrayList<>();

    //.........

     return excludeList;
    }
```

but when I used "?" question character wildcard is worked me I don't know any relation why so?

```
private static List<String> getExcludeMethodList(List<?> data, List<String> filteredList) {
```

Comment: if you get an compile error, share the error message.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you must declare the type `<T>` which stands for *a concrete unbound type*. `?` stands for *any type* which you do not have to declare.